# Unable to open console screen

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to send data from an Arduino to ubuntu mate through Bluetooth hc 05. I am able to connect to my Bluetooth but unable to get console screen on ubuntu to see the Bluetooth output. Can anyone suggest how to open console screen of hc05?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: actually iam planning to send output of arduino to raspberry pi 7 inch display screen installed with ubuntu mate through bluetooth hc05.The bluetooth of pi is paired successfully with hc05 but unable to open console screen to observe my output